# Finding a word using std::regex_token_iterator (not necessarilly) to find the char position in string

Tags: c++, regex

```
string zodis;
sregex_token_iterator it(eil.begin(), eil.end(), std::regex("[A-Za-z]+"));
sregex_token_iterator reg_end;

for (; it != reg_end; ++it) {
    zodis = it -> str();
    /* ... */
}
```

Basically I get the word using the above code, but I want to find out at what **position** the string's `zodis` first character in the string `eil` is (the string `zodis` is taken from `eil`)

I tried pointing to the iterator returned from `begin()`, but that just gives me the **characters**.

Any ideas?

Comment: `std::string::find`.

Comment: what if i have more than 1 of the same word, how do i find the one i need, not something after it, taken i will have to go through each word, and what if the words have different chars before and after them?basically something like "//one() (-one])" will it still work?

Comment: Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find, especially the `pos` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so i figured out a way to cleanly do it.

```
    int basepoint=0;
    while(whatever)
    {
      int c1=zodis.end()-zodis.begin();//the length of the word
      int c2=eil.find(zodis,basepoint);//the starting position of the word
      basepoint+=c1+c2;//start point for the find function for the next loop
     }
```

this will find all the word start points(even if the whole line is the same word)

if you had the text file of

```
word word word word word
```

using this

```
cout << c1 << " " << c2;
```

where c1 is the word's taken from the string length, and c2 is the starting position,
would give you

```
4 0
4 5
4 10
4 15
4 20
```